# Validate XML against XSD in PL/SQL ORACLE

Tags: xml, oracle

I try to validate an XML file against an XSD file, so i found the code bellow on the internet, but when i execute it, it raise only the first error and not all of them. My XML file contains 2 errors if i checked it whith another tool.

```
BEGIN
  v_xml := DBMS_XMLDOM.GETXMLTYPE(v_doc).createSchemaBasedXML('http://localhost/XSD/RFF_Shema.xsd');
  v_xml.schemaValidate();
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
   dbms_output.put_line ('Error => '||sqlerrm);  
END;
```

This is the error raised :

```
Error => ORA-31038: Valeur number non valide : "1,5"
```

But when I correct it, it raises this one :

```
Error => ORA-30936: Maximum number (1) XML node elements exceeded 'testnode'
```

My goal is to raise all the errors of the XML document. Help me please and thanks for your answers.

Comment: You would need to create your own XML parser that contains the logic you’re after, if you want to do this inside the database. Oracle simply reports the first error it encounters.

Comment: thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by Boneist, Oracle only raise the first error encounters.

I Used JAVA in PL/SQL to get all errors of the XML document.